# map existing mysql database with gorm

Tags: mysql, grails, dictionary, joomla, grails-orm

I'm trying to map a (small part of a) Joomla MySQL database using GORM with Grails 2.0.

I'm reading a book on the argument (Grails) and googling the web for tech article, but I still need a good reference to map Groovy/Java types to MySQL fields.

I'm starting with a simple table `jos_bannerclient`.

```
class BannerClient {
    String name
    String contact
    String email
    String notes
    String editor = ''

    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false)
        contact(nullable:true)
        email(nullable:true)
        notes(nullable:true)
        editor(nullable:true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'joomla'
        table 'jos_bannerclient'
        id column:'cid', type:'int'
        notes column:'extrainfo', type:'text'
        version false
    }
}
```

At this point the record is generated in the database but if I save the domain with `failOnError:true` I get this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

I've problems mapping the checked_out `TINYINT` field. The only thing for GORM to validate that field is to declare it as `Boolean`, why it doen't work with `Byte`?

I've also some doubt on how to map a MySQL `TIME` field like `checked_out_time`.

I've also read some part of Hibernate documentation, but still not gaining the needed knowledge to accomplish this task!

Anyone can help please?

Comment: I've started a new conversation on grails community forum on this topic and more joomla <-> grails integration, at http://goo.gl/ARiug

Comment: You might find this plugin useful http://www.grails.org/plugin/db-reverse-engineer

Comment: Can you give us more information about the original table? You mention the 'checked_out' and 'checked_out_time' for example.

Answer (score 2):

You are indicating "type" but should be indicating "sqlType", which is why I believe you are having issues with TINYINT and having to use a Boolean instead of Byte. Id is an int (well actually bigint) by default, but it won't complain at you about that unless you are using dbCreate = "validate" and the other values are strings so that won't necessarily give you an issue with compatibility for notes.

```
static mapping = {
    datasource 'joomla'
    table 'jos_bannerclient'
    id column:'cid', sqlType:'int'
    notes column:'extrainfo', sqlType:'text'
    version false
}
```

As for the TIME issue, I have been able to specify type TIMESTAMP without a problem, so I can imagine TIME will work fine as well. All SQL types should be supported. For example:

```
static mapping = {
  dateCreated sqlType: 'TIMESTAMP', defaultValue: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
}
```